# Naming convention when submitting separate iPhone and iPad app versions

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I have an iPhone app named XXXX-YYYY, now i have built a separate iPad version of this program, not a universal, and my idea was to name it XXXX-iPad-YYY. This was rejected due to the "iPad" piece in the name.

May i ask for some advice how you would name the iPad version as i cannot use the same name as the iPhone version, tried that, and i cannot use "iPad" in the name.

I have checked around a bit but not found anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the App store for example names the Apple has previously approved, such as with the "HD" suffix.  Or Apple may allow "... for iPad" as a suffix in some cases.

Comment: HD is the most often used way around this; however, if you want your users to truly love you, go universal with an in-app purchase for upgraded iPad features if you simply must.